# How to delete rows based on a column value

Tags: excel, vba

I'm attempting to write a small piece of code for an ActiveX control button.

I have a spreadsheet of "Master Inventory". Columns "B" through "N" contain data about the inventory. Once the inventory is shipped, it's notated in column "N" with a "Y" (for Yes).

1. I want my ActiveX Control button to ONLY delete rows (B3:N98) where column "N" = "Y".
2. I do not want formatting or formulas to be deleted - ONLY values.
3. I would like the data to be condensed and pushed to the top of the list after rows are deleted.

I have been successful with #2, but not #1 or #3. I'm deleting all rows but can't seem to get my "If" statement correct to only recognize those "Y" values.

```
Private Sub CommandButton1_Click()
    On Error Resume Next
    For I = 3 To 498
        If Range(I, "N").Text = "Y" Then
            Range("B3:N27").SpecialCells(xlCellTypeConstants).ClearContents
        End If
    Next I
End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

When deleting rows, you need to start at the bottom and work upward so that the remaining row numbers don't change.  Column "N" is 14, so you can use logic like this.

```vbs
Sub DeleteRows()
Dim I As Long
For I = 498 To 3 Step -1
If Cells(I, 14).Value = "Y" Then
Rows(I).EntireRow.Delete
End If
Next I
End Sub
```

Comment: Thanks Weston. When i run this I'm returned with a Run Time error of 13 - Type mIsmatch.

Comment: Any suggestions on how to resolve this? I also have to take out the Sub DeleteRows() because I'm using this in a Control Button and must begin with Private Sub CommandButton_Click()

Comment: @Ashley Van Bibber I'm assuming that the error is on the IF statement (let me know if that's wrong), so you may have numeric and text values in the same column. Here is how you can force the cell value to text before comparing it.

Comment: `Private Sub CommandButton_Click()  
Dim I As Long  
Dim strX as String  
For I = 498 To 3 Step -1  
strX = Cells(I, 14).Value  
If UCase$(strX) = "Y" Then  
Rows(I).EntireRow.Delete  
End If  
Next I  
End Sub`

Answer (score 0):

A much faster way is to create a range object to hold all of the rows marked for deletion and then perform the delete all at once at the end. Deleting rows one-by-one inside of a loop can be painfully slow in Excel, especially as the number of rows grows in size.

Try this:

```
Public Sub DeleteRowsWithRange()

Dim rngLoop As Range
Dim rngMyRange As Range

    For Each rngLoop In Columns("N").Cells

    If rngLoop.Value = "" Then ' This is your exist clause. You can change this depending on your worksheet structure.
        Exit For  
    ElseIf rngLoop.Value = "N" Then
        If rngMyRange Is Nothing Then
            Set rngMyRange = rngLoop.EntireRow
        Else
            Set rngMyRange = Union(rngMyRange, rngLoop.EntireRow)
        End If
    End If

    Next rngLoop

    rngMyRange.Delete xlShiftUp

    Set rngLoop = Nothing
    Set rngMyRange = Nothing

End Sub
```